# Bookmark and open multiple files in Windows 8 Reader app

Tags: windows-8

I want to create a bookmark to a page in an pdf file in the Windows 8 Reader app. How can I do this?

Also, how can I open multiple pdf files al once with the Reader app? Once I open a new pdf file, it automaticaaly replaces the old one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you can have only one PDF open in Windows Reader at a time.

Regarding creating bookmarks, you can not create bookmarks using Windows Reader. You can however, navigate previously created bookmarks using other PDF readers.

To navigate: Right click -> More -> Bookmarks

Comment: It's a shame -- Windows reader is actually a really nice "feeling" full screen touch PDF reader. :(